# How to construct a URI with parameters using URIBuilder?

Tags: java, parameters, uri, uribuilder

How to construct a `URI` like `www.google.com/p1/p2?what&k1=v1&k2=v2`  using `URIBuilder` ?
When I use Java's URIBuilder.setParameter(), I must pass in an name and a value.
How can I construct the above uri without using URIBuilder.setCustomQuery() ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder()
    .setScheme("https")
    .setHost("www.google.com")
    .setPath("/p1/p2")
    .addParameter("what",null)
    .addParameter("k1", "v1")
    .addParameter("k2", "v2")
builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

well,, call `setParameter(name, null)` solve this.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html)
for example

```
UriBuilder.fromPath("{arg1}").fragment("{arg2}").build("foo", "bar")
```

this code generates foo#bar

or write your own writer it is just a string concatenation